# Можно ли сохранять позицию скролла RecycleView в BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view

Есть MainActivity в которой расположен BottomNavigationView который переключает фрагменты. В каждом фрагменте есть RecycleView с довольно длинным списком. При переходе фрагмент разрушается, позиция скролла в RecycleView состояние все пропадает. При таких переходах onSaveInstanceState не вызывается. Короче надо что то делать. Я думаю что могу написать свой  костыль, который может даже будет работать, но может есть уже готовое решение. Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/bkg_bottom_bar"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/mwhite"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/mwhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```